# No data in collection LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR for 2022

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-8

LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR data for year 2022 is not available. what is reason and when it can be available in Google Earth Engine?

Answer (score 1):

You are using a Landsat Collection 1 image collection, which is deprecated and will not be receiving new data. (Both the EE Code Editor and the [dataset info page](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/LANDSAT_LC08_C01_T1_SR) will tell you about this.) You should use Collection 2 instead.

> #### Landsat collection status
>
> Pre-Collection 1: no longer being produced
> by USGS, unmaintained by Earth Engine, still available in Earth Engine
> but will eventually be purged.
>
> Collection 1: produced by USGS until 2022-01-01, maintained by Earth
> Engine until 2023-01-01.
>
> Collection 2: primary collection produced by USGS, increasing product
> availability in Earth Engine as ingestion backlog is processed. See
> the Data Catalog's Landsat page for currently available products.

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/landsat#landsat-collection-status